# take the address of a member function without referring to the instance's class by concrete name?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, auto

Now that we have `auto` keyword, I'd like to be able to take the address of a member of class-instance without having to statically refer to its class.

e.g. (old-skool)

```
MyInterestingClass & foo = m_holder.GetInteresting();
foo.SetEnableNotification(false);
ScopeGuard restore_notifications = MakeObjGuard(foo, &MyInterestingClass::SetEnableNotification, true);
// do stuf...
```

c++11 using auto???

```
auto & foo = m_holder.GetInteresting();
foo.SetEnableNotification(false);
ScopeGuard restore_notifications = MakeObjGuard(foo, &foo.SetEnableNotification, true);
// do stuf...
```

However, &foo.memfun doesn't compile.  What's the syntax / canonical approach to this?  Surely we don't want to refer to the concrete type of foo if we can avoid it, as otherwise `auto` seems to be weak-sauce indeed, no?

Comment: have you tried `&decltype(foo)::SetEnableNotification`? I would guess that would work

Comment: I think the approach nowadays (at least for a scope guard-like class) would simply be to use a lambda: `auto restore_notifications = make_scope_guard([&]{ foo.SetEnableNotification(true); });`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. `&decltype(foo)::SetEnableNotifications` -> `error C2039: 'SetEnableNotifications' : is not a member of '`global namespace''`

Comment: @Mordachai That's a bug in Visual Studio, using `::` after `decltype(...)` always fails. One of the workarounds I've seen is to typedef `decltype(...)` and then refer to the nested thing using the typedef.

Comment: @Praetorian: There's an inherent problem beside that.

Comment: @Xeo Yep, I saw your comment on the answer below. But the error being reported by VS is incorrect nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (in GCC 4.7.2 at least):

```
ScopeGuard restore_notifications = MakeObjGuard(foo,
    &std::remove_reference<decltype(foo)>::type::SetEnableNotification, true);
```

I tried it in a reduced case and it compiles fine.

Comment: No, because `foo` is `MyInterestingClass&`.

Comment: Thanks for showing how it could be made to work. I think @GManNickG has it right with using a lambda then.  The above syntax leaves rather a lot to be desired.

Comment: sure, I'll leave it here since it answers the question, in case anyone else needs it.